# Including maximum possible distance of route as restriction when using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

Using the network analyst of ArcGIS, I am trying to find the possible routes in my network from a determined starting/ending point which the maximum distance should not exceed 90 kilometers. I am using the network analyst to calculate it but I am having problems to set the restriction of maximum distance of 90 kilometers.

Can anyone help me with that?

The reason I am using this tool is that I also have weights associated with my roads. So each route calculated gives the sum of the weights of the roads in which the car pass by. So at the end I can find the route below 90 kilometers that gives me the highest sum of weights.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are trying to find all possible roads for which there is a route between two specified points that does not exceed the maximum distance (90 kilometers).

You could try calculating a service area from each point and then determine where the sum of the travel distance for each point is less than your maximum.

This is the same concept used in the raster-based corridor analysis in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/creating-a-least-cost-corridor.htm